# Noun to describe a "typo-filled" letter

Tags: expressions, synonyms, orthography, errors

I am changing my e-mail signature on my phone to read:

> Sent from my Samsung Galaxy S4. Please do not mistake my brevity and/or
>   misspellings for apathy and/or ignorance.

I am looking for a better word than misspellings to describe my email that might be filled with typos.

"Misspellings" makes sense, but it doesn't feel like it truly fits in. *I think it's because all the other nouns describe a quality (mass, or non-count nouns), while "misspellings" describe an actual, physical thing (count noun).* "Error prone" sounds better, but doesn't make sense lexically. Is there a word that fits here that sounds like it fits with the rest of the nouns in the sentence?

*I am more looking for a word that describes an email that is "full of typos", not a synonym for the typos themselves.*

Thanks!

---

From suggestions, this is what I have changed it to:

> Sent from my phone. Please do not mistake my brevity and solecism for apathy and ignorance.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Is "errors" too ambiguous for your purposes?

Comment: "Sent from my Samsung Galaxy S4" should be sufficient. The rest is implied.

Comment: @KristinaLopez "errors","misspellings" isn't, shall I say, "elegant" enough. But thanks...technically that word fits, just no better than misspellings.

Comment: Maybe we need a neologism like *thumb-screw-ups*? Or *thumblebums*?

Comment: How about Autocorrect? ;)  It has a different meaning entirely, but I think your audience will appreciate the term, given the context.

Comment: Why don't you just proofread your emails?

Comment: Wouldn't 'typo-filled' be a contradiction in terms?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How so?

Comment: Shouldn't such a document include say 'tupo=fiiled'?

Comment: @dberm22: *Please don't mistake my butchery of the English language to be intentional or unintentional.*  -- This should cover all your bases This also gets rid of the *and/or* issue.

Comment: Isn't it kind of funny that you'd put a signature on every email indicating that you were too apathetic to hit backspace a few times and fix your typos, but asking everyone to not think you're apathetic?

Comment: @George Typing on a phone inevitably leads to typos and auto-correct failures that you fail to notice because (unlike on a computer where you look at what you're typing) you're looking at the letters your fingers are hitting (or missing) as you type. For a few lines, going back to read everything through end to end to find typos isn't much hassle, but small typing boxes and long texts do not mix well. Typos _will_ occur.

Comment: You say that with such certainty, but I've never had enough of a typo problem to have to apologize in a signature.  It's possible, and very easy, to type well on a phone.

Comment: No offense, but if you can't be bothered to write complete sentences and fix typos in your e-mails, then you're being an e-mail boor. When I see a disclaimer like that at the bottom of messages, it's just a sign to me that my interlocutor is not just being rude accidentally, but that they've gone to the trouble of premeditating their boorishness. And if they've gone to trouble to use elegant language, curt, misspelled messages sting even more. My advice: never use an e-mail signature like that.

Comment: Beware typos. "Every time you make a typo, the errorists win."

Comment: My signature is "Clumsily thumbed into a phone".  I'm not begging forgiveness for my errors, but implying the message may be subject to later correction.  I'll apologize later if I get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While they're not generally used as mass nouns, which would describe the "quality" of having errors, the following words can be used as such, and I think these words fit better with the overall theme of the message:

> solecism: 1) a mistake in speech or writing, or 2) an impolite or improper way of behaving
>
> malapropism: The use of an incorrect word in place of a word with a similar sound, resulting in a nonsensical, often humorous utterance.

"Solecism" is more correct in the general sense as "Malapropism" does not cover all typos, however the comical connotation of "Malapropism" is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use *typos*. It encapsulates the uniquely digital nature of the mistakes you are making. They are not *Misspellings* as such because you actually do know how to spell the words in question, so you should use a word which is more about input errors than knowledge gaps.

*Flubs* or *goofs* might also fit in some other context, but it will make total sense to anyone who reads the message to just say *typos*.

Comment: Right. Something like "Sent from my phone. Excuse typos" should be fine. Avoid too much anxiety to show off your phone model and education :-)

Comment: Yea, I suppose you are both right. I was more just looking for a word that describes an email which is "full of typos", not a word for the typos themselves.

Comment: "infelicities" is a good word.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *[fat finger](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/fat-finger)*:

> Used to refer to clumsy or inaccurate typing, typically resulting from
>   one finger striking two keys at the same time.

So your sig could be:

> Sent from my Samsung Galaxy S4. Expect brevity and fat-finger mistakes.

Comment: Foreigners or non-hip people may think you have notably fat fingers, though.

Comment: Hmm, possibly. But isn't that the action of misspelling something, not the actual misspellings themselves?

Comment: If you really want to spell it out, refer to the misspellings as _fat-finger mistakes_. (I modified my answer accordingly.)

Comment: Not all have fat fingers :-) LOL I would avoid specifying the brand of phone. It seems like you need to show off it.

Comment: @Pam Thanks. I was just adding my stuff onto the end of the default sig. I guess I can remove that part.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it. Sorry, I did not want to imply you wanted to show off. Just being brutally frank about how it sounded (to me) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just lead by example:

> Snet form my pohne

... which is both terse and filled with typos!

But in all seriousness, I think this is more than sufficient:

> Sent from my phone; please excuse my errors and brevity.

I substituted "errors" for "typos" because "typo" is simply short-hand for "typographical error", so I've applied the plural to the noun instead of the adjective.

Comment: Instead: “Sent from my phone; please excuse its errors and my brevity”

Comment: The phone doesn't have errors or brevity.

Comment: twodave, every complex software product has errors.  That aside, blaming the spelling and typing errors in your message on the phone is intended to be humorous and most people would so understand it.  Also, the version I gave attributes message brevity to the person sending it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I assumed you were correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

Sent from my Samsung Galaxy S4. Please do not mistake my brevity and/or malapropisms (darn predictive text) for disrespect or attempts at humour.

I think the above sounds cooler.